# Javascript code not working inside wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to create a number of lists   on a word press page. Each in its own div. For Example:

```html
    <strong>List One</strong>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Item One</li>
        <li>Item Two</li>
        <li>Item Three</li>
        <li>Item Four</li>
        <li>Item Five</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <strong>List Two</strong>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Item Uno</li>
        <li>Item Dos</li>
        <li>Item Tre</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I would like the list header text to be clickable

```
<strong><a href="#">List One</a></strong>
```

and hide or show when clicked.

where, the default should be hidden

```html
<div style="display: none";>
 ...
</div>
```

I can do this using javascript 9see below), however, it seems to conflict with wordpress /php/ template/plugins, etc.

Although my page has only text and the code (see below), it will not work 100%. it takes multiple clicks sometimes for it to work

```
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if (e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
      else
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    <strong><a href="#"  onclick="toggle_visibility('list_one');">List One</a></strong>
    <div id="list_one" style="display: none">
      <ul>
        <li>Item One</li>
        <li>Item Two</li>
        <li>Item Three</li>
        <li>Item Four</li>
        <li>Item Five</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <strong><a href="#"  onclick="toggle_visibility('list_two');">List Two</a></strong>
    <div id="list_two" style="display: none">
      <ul>
        <li>Item Uno</li>
        <li>Item Dos</li>
        <li>Item Tre</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Question:**  Can this be done another way in order to get same affect. i.e. click a link andshow or hide DIV ?

Comment: Are you putting the JavaScript code in a WordPress page or post itself? WordPress will strip out any JS you enter that way.

Comment: You also don't even have the code in `<script></script>` tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your script via `wp_footer` hook. Just enter your javascript function inside the callback function.

```
    function custom_js_functions(){
      <script>
          //your code goes here.
      </script>
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_js_functions');
```